# How to cast an integer to a boolean in a MySQL SELECT clause?

Tags: mysql, select, datatypes

I'm new here so be kind to me. I have the following scenario:

I have many tables which, for the sake of simplicity, are represented in a View in my MySQL database. My problem is that I need a value in this view representing if it is one kind of event or another (a simple boolean), which I tried to achieve with:

```
`gu`.`StoppingUnitEventME` = `ese`.`MonitoringElement` AS `IsStopingEvent`
```

The result is represented as int, and so is read by Entity Framework. The problem is that I really need a boolean return value, which I tried to achieve with:

```
CAST((`gu`.`StoppingUnitEventME` = `ese`.`MonitoringElement`) as boolean) AS `IsStopingEvent`
```

This resulted in an error, one that is not displayed to me in MySQL Workbench (I only receive that annoying "You have an error in ...").

Can you guys please help me out?

Tried to solve it in my application, but I really preffer this solved in the database, since it will be used by other software later.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try using the [`IF()` function:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if)

```
SELECT IF(`gu`.`StoppingUnitEventME`=`ese`.`MonitoringElement`, TRUE, FALSE) 
FROM ...
```

or

```
SELECT IF(`gu`.`StoppingUnitEventME`=`ese`.`MonitoringElement`, 1, 0) 
FROM ...
```

Even without the `IF()` function, running

```
mysql> select ('rolando' = 'rolando') str_compare;
+-------------+
| str_compare |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

yield 0 or 1 using the mysql client

**The problem is this:** [`CAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) and [`CONVERT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) **can only accept and return the following types**:

- `BINARY[(N)]`
- `CHAR[(N)]`
- `DATE`
- `DATETIME`
- `DECIMAL[(M[,D])]`
- `SIGNED [INTEGER]`
- `TIME`
- `UNSIGNED [INTEGER]`

Since `BOOLEAN` is not in this list, it can never be returned by `CAST()` or `CONVERT()`

You could use the `IF()` function to generate strings

```
SELECT IF(`gu`.`StoppingUnitEventME`=`ese`.`MonitoringElement`, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') 
FROM ...
```

Comment: A boolean is an alias for `tinyint`. Under no circumstance does `IF` return a `tinyint` so I can't see how this answer is right or accepted.

Comment: @EvanCarroll My answer is meant to bypass CAST and CONVERT altogether..Using IF function does what his framework won’t do, which is recognize BOOLEAN as an INT (4-byte) rather than TINYINT (1-byte). In this case, you have blame the framework for not working with BOOLEAN values.

Answer (score 15):

You can do it very simple way, without use of redundant IF() statement:

```
... `YourField` IS NOT NULL AS `YourField` ...
```

Comment: Honestly this is the easiest way. And works for my case.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can also try the classic boolean coercion:

SELECT NOT NOT (whatever);

The good thing about this is that it naturally preserves NULLs, whereas most of the answers here do not.

If you want to coerce NULL to FALSE, then do

SELECT IFNULL(NOT NOT (whatever), FALSE);

Comment: I wonder, how does this achieve converting an integer to boolean?

Answer (score 4):

This is currently impossible.

- MySQL doesn't have a real `BOOLEAN` type, (or a real array type.. or a real JSON type). It has an alias for `TINYINT`.
- Any condition returns an integer. This is the fastest datatype for a CPU, and presumably this implementation detail is reflected here. For instance, `'true' IS TRUE` and `1=1` both return `1` as an `int`.
- CAST does not provide a `TINYINT` format.

As far as I can tell you can neither demote a type, nor produce a tinyint in a `SELECT`.

I would *highly* suggest migrating to PostgreSQL. It's so much less terrifying... and liberating.

Comment: It's possible now, you can [create a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759250/how-do-i-convert-a-mysql-function-result-to-tinyint1) to do that, not good but it work.

Answer (score 4):

> Use mysql function CAST_TO_BIT
>
> Examples:

```
SELECT CAST_TO_BIT(1);
```

> *Mysql:* SELECT **CAST_TO_BIT(0)**; -> jdbc driver -> *Java:* Boolean **false**;
>
> *Mysql:* SELECT **CAST_TO_BIT(1)**; -> jdbc driver -> *Java:* Boolean **true**;
>
> *Mysql:* SELECT **CAST_TO_BIT(NULL)**; -> jdbc driver -> *Java:* **NULL**;

Answer (score 3):

You also can use "CASE":

`SELECT CASE WHEN yourField=testValue THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END as boolFieldName`

Comment: You should cast it as boolean, if not it is a char field.

Comment: Sometimes the consumer of your query wants a character, though

Answer (score 0):

`CAST(IF(col_name = 1, 'true', 'false') AS JSON)` may work for some use cases.

As of MySQL 5.7.8 there is support for a native JSON data type defined by RFC 7159. For my use case I had an `INT` column that was always either 0 or 1, but I needed the output as bool `true` or `false` not string "true" or "false".

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-converting-between-types