# Define calculated column of BOOLEAN/TINYINT(1) type in a View?

Tags: mysql, view, datatypes, cast, mariadb-10.1

I'm configuring a View which contains calculated columns that should be returning Boolean results. Here's an anonymised version of the view:

```
CREATE VIEW `ItemView` AS
SELECT Item.ID
    ,ItemProperty1
    ,ItemProperty2
    ,ItemProperty3
    ,EXISTS(SELECT ItemComponent.ItemID FROM ItemComponent WHERE ItemComponent.ItemID = Item.ID) AS Operation1Required
    ,Item.Property4 <> ItemType.Property AS Operation2Required
FROM Item
INNER JOIN ItemType
    ON Item.TypeID = ItemType.ID
ORDER BY ItemProperty2 ASC
```

At the moment, MariaDB metadata says that the type for the "Operation1Required" and "Operation2Required" columns is INT, even though they are both expressions with fundamentally Boolean results.

I want them to be BOOLEAN/TINYINT(1), because the view is being read by a strongly-typed client which is expecting Boolean values for these columns.

But the CAST() and CONVERT() functions in MySQL/MariaDB 10.1 don't seem to be able to convert to TINYINT(1).

Is there another way I can specify the correct data type for these calculated columns in the View?

I looked at [How to cast an integer to a boolean in a MySQL SELECT clause?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12569/how-to-cast-an-integer-to-a-boolean-in-a-mysql-select-clause) and tried it out, but the results of `IF(expression, TRUE, FALSE)` still seem to be `INT` according to phpMyAdmin's report of the view's structure.

Comment: I looked at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12569/how-to-cast-an-integer-to-a-boolean-in-a-mysql-select-clause and tried it out, but the results of IF(expression, TRUE, FALSE) still seem to be INT according to phpMyAdmin's report of the view's structure.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, why are you listing as a possible duplicate a question that I cited in my comment above yours, and already explained why it doesn’t answer my question?

Comment: I don't always agree ;) Likely, I agree with you that the chosen answer there is wrong. It doesn't address the question at all. But, the question itself is a duplicate of this. You're both asking the same thing.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. The accepted answer over there is rubbish but a CORRECT answer to that question would answer this also.

Comment: On that note, a non-dupe would be to ask another question looking for a workaround for the "strongly-typed client" that may be more fun. (btw I upvoted this even though I think it's a dupe)

Comment: Hey Hydragyrum, My answer (https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12570/877) is meant to bypass CAST and CONVERT altogether. `IF(expression, TRUE, FALSE)` still gets victimized if you want a boolean. This is why I suggested using `IF` to assign string values rather than try to stress over getting a boolean value.  My answer was just a workaround.

Comment: You could just change `EXISTS(...)` with `IF(EXISTS(...),1,0)`. Seems cheesy, but Hey this is MYSQL. Therefore, Evan's answer is quite valid and is a workaround of a more permanent nature.

Answer (score 4):

This is currently impossible.

- MySQL doesn't have a real `BOOLEAN` type, (or a real array type.. or a real JSON type). It has an alias for `TINYINT`.
- Any condition returns an integer. This is the fastest datatype for a CPU, and presumably this implementation detail is reflected here. For instance, `'true' IS TRUE` and `1=1` both return `1` as an `int`.
- CAST does not provide a `TINYINT` format.

I would *highly* suggest migrating to PostgreSQL. It's so much less terrifying... and liberating.

Comment: I am sorry MySQL has a lot of cheesy things to it. Your answer here is quite understandable (+1).

Comment: I tried everything too but I couldn't make the cast I wanted. In my case using Dapper I was unable to associate the boolean type to the constructor of a class and therefore I had to use the long type and subsequently convert to bool